# Advanced Query Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, case

Got this problem, i have a sell products history table, now the problem is when I set a date range filter for example Show all products but only show the quantity sell in the week per product, else show 0.

I think a case statement, but this case override the return result with 0 always.

```
(case when (stock_move.date between '1/11/2017' and '20/11/2017') then
   round(sum(stock_move.product_quantity))
else 
   0
end) as sell
```

I hope you guys tell me where I'm failing and you help me :), Thanks!

Comment: Please post your full query and the structure of your tables including some test data

Comment: Can you please review your question too, either its the coffee not kicking in or you need to make your question more clear and concise.   Also, along with the full query, can you add an example table of what you're trying to achieve.   I have a vague idea of what you might need, but hard to explain without what @SEarle1986 asked.

Answer (score 0):

If we use an aggregate function (`sum`) in the `select` query then we have to mention the column name in a `group by` clause; only then will it execute the query.

```
select (case when (stock_move.date between '1/11/2017' and '20/11/2017') then
   round(sum(stock_move.product_quantity))
else 
   0
end) as sell from table_name
group by stock_move.date
```